# How to define a custom view to generate a xlsx file in Rails 5.2 for downloading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ParametersController, I defined the **export** method to download a list of parameters as a xlsx formated file:

```
  # Get /parameters_list/1/export.xlsx
  def export
    ### Exports the parameters attached to @parameters_lists in a Workbook
    workbook = WriteXLSX.new("./public/#{@parameters_list.code}_parameters.xlsx")
    title = workbook.add_format(:font  => 'Calibri', :size  => 16, :color => 'blue', :bold  => 1)
    header = workbook.add_format(:font  => 'Calibri', :size  => 12, :color => 'black', :bold  => 1)
    data = workbook.add_format(:font  => 'Calibri', :size  => 10, :color => 'black', :bold  => 0)
    workbook.set_properties(
    :title    => "Parameters lists export: #{@parameters_list.code}",
    :subject  => 'This file contains exported parameters',
    :author   => 'Open Data Quality',
    :comments => translation_for(@parameters_list.name_translations)
    #,
    #:hyperlink_base => url_for @parameters_list
    )

    ### write Description sheet
    cover = workbook.add_worksheet('Parameters list')
    cover.write(0, 0, @parameters_list.code, title)
    cover.write(1, 0, translation_for(@parameters_list.name_translations), header)
    index = 3
    @parameters_list.attributes.map do |name, value|
      cover.write(index, 0, name, header)
      cover.write(index, 1, value, data)
      index += 1
    end

    ### write Data sheet
    data_sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Parameters')
    index = 0

    ## Headers
    # Write attributes headers
    @parameters_list.parameters.first.attributes.each do |attribute, value|
      data_sheet.write(0, index, attribute, header)
      index += 1
    end

    # Add translations headers
    list_of_languages.order(:property).each do |locution|
      data_sheet.write(0, index, "Name_#{locution.code}", header)
      index += 1
      data_sheet.write(0, index, "Description_#{locution.code}", header)
      index += 1
    end

    ## Data
    @parameters_list.parameters.each_with_index do |parameter, line_index|
      index = 0
      # Write attributes
      parameter.attributes.each do |attribute, value|
        data_sheet.write(line_index + 1, index, value, data)
        index += 1
      end

      # Add translations
      list_of_languages.order(:property).each do |locution|
        data_sheet.write(line_index + 1, index, parameter.name_translations.where(language: locution.property).first&.translation, data)
        index += 1
        data_sheet.write(line_index + 1, index, parameter.description_translations.where(language: locution.property).first&.translation, data)
        index += 1
      end

    end

    # close workbook
    workbook.close

    send_file "./public/#{@parameters_list.code}_parameters.xlsx", type: "application/xlsx"

  end
```

With respect to the MVC architecture, I think this would rather be defined as a view, accessible through a URL with specified format, such as `my_server/parameters_lists/15.xlsx` relying on the show method:

```
  # GET /parameters_list/1
  # GET /parameters_list/1.json
  # GET /parameters_list/1.csv
  # GET /parameters_list/1.xlsx
  def show
    ### @parameters_list retrieved by callback function

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @parameters_list.parameters }
      format.csv { send_data @parameters_list.parameters.to_csv }
      format.xlsx # uses specific template to generate the a file
    end
  end
```

I tried several ways to move and encapsulate the code into a show.xlsx.erb file, but it does not generate
more than an text file without data.

Can you help me find out how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [caxlsx_rails](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx_rails) gem

For eg: Create the template with the `.xlsx.axlsx` extension

sample.xlsx.axlsx

```rb
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Samples") do |sheet|
  @samples.each do |sample|
    sheet.add_row [sample]
  end
end
```

```rb
format.xlsx {
  response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="my_new_filename.xlsx"'
}
```

For more info you can go [here](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx_rails)

Comment: I finally swichted to the write_xlsx_rails gem, because write_xlsx seems more covinient to format xlsx files. I took this version: https://github.com/DatozMX/write_xlsx_rails.git

Comment: @user1185081 [write_xlsx_rails](https://github.com/DatozMX/write_xlsx_rails.git) is not being maintained.

Comment: Yes, I had to update it to get it to work properly... https://github.com/fchampreux/write_xlsx_rails

Comment: Now I have a warning

```DEPRECATION WARNING: Single arity template handlers are deprecated. Template handlers must
now accept two parameters, the view object and the source for the view object.
Change:
  >> WriteXlsxRails::WriteXlsxBuilder.call(template)
To:
  >> WriteXlsxRails::WriteXlsxBuilder.call(template, source)```

Comment: @araslanov_e what version of ruby and [`caxlsx_rail`](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx_rails) gem you are using?